# set attribute in html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Based on condition `status == "complete"`, I need to set an attribute disabled to a input tag.

Using javascript, we can add using setAttribute method

```
var b = document.querySelector("input"); 
b.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
```

And I know if I use 2 tags in HTML code I can do

```
<input ng-if="status == 'complete'" value="complete" disabled/>
<input ng-if="status != 'complete'" value="in progress"/>
```

In HTML, is there any way to do directly?

Comment: `ng-disabled="status == 'complete'"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-disabled, ng-value`:

```
<input ng-value="doneValue()" 
       ng-disabled="status == 'complete'"/>
```

Here in the $scope:

```
$scope.doneValue= function(){
   var value = $scope.value || 0;

   if($scope.status == 'complete'){
    value = "complete";
   }else{
    value = "In Progress"
   }
   return value;
}
```

and now you don't need `ng-if`.

Answer (score 0):

**you're looking for:**

```
<input ng-disabled="status == 'complete'" value="complete"/>
```

this sets the disabled attribute on the element if the expression inside `ngDisabled` evaluates to truthy.